# problem in installing vs2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

while installing vs2005 professional ...i am getting dis error"the windows installer package"d:\softwares\microsoft visual studio 8\vs_setup.msi could not be opened.chooose retry to try again.choose cancel for exit setup"....i am not able to proceed further after retry....what shud i do?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like 3rd party software (AV, etc) or incomplete/corrupt installation source.

I'd run through this checklist mentioned at the beginning of this thread to see if it's either of those:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/60f71a54-506e-4c70-be98-e993ce6d1ddf/

Then, if it still isn't working, try the uninstall and registry cleanup steps that worked a few posts down and attempt to install again.